# Dialog Box Code Optimization

Tags: android, optimization, dialog

I am working on optimizing my code on an application I am making. I am not advanced in any way, so i could seriously use some help.

I am creating Alert Dialog Boxes, and i am used to use this as a layout

```
private void doScript2() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert_box=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert_box.setIcon(R.drawable.caution);
    alert_box.setTitle("Caution");
    alert_box.setMessage("Mount external sd as NTFS at boot?");
    alert_box.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "External SD will be mounted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                ....
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RootToolsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    alert_box.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alert_box.show();
}
```

After reading Google's examples i have managed to create this.

```
private static final int DIALOG_TWRESTORE = 202;
private static final int DIALOG_TWRESTART = 204;
private static final int DIALOG_TWONESIX = 205;
private static final int DIALOG_TWONENINE = 206;
private static final int DIALOG_TWTWOFOUR = 207;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TWRESTORE:
        return createDialog("Restore", "Are you sure you want to restore your TW?");
    case DIALOG_TWRESTART:
        return createDialog("Restart", "Restart TW?");
    case DIALOG_TWONESIX:
        return createDialog("Resize to 6x6", "Are you blablabla of TW?");
    case DIALOG_TWONENINE:
        return createDialog("Resize to 5x5", "Are you on blablabla of TW?");
    case DIALOG_TWTWOFOUR:
        return createDialog("Resize to 4x5", "Are you on blablabla of TW?");
    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
}

private Dialog createDialog(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.question)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //I want to pass on a parameter from the above class to use within the dialog
            **parametergoeshere*();             
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        } });
    return builder.create();
}
```

My main question is that i am making a Yes/No Dialog box which i want to do something different upon the click of the Yes button. I want to pass on this in a similar way to a parameter so i do not repeat the code i used to use. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried the following code which doesn't work.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TWRESTORE:
        return createDialog("Restore", "Are you sure you want to restore your TW?", Commands.doTWBackup());
    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
}

private Dialog createDialog(String title, String message, Object param) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.question)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //I want to pass on a parameter from the above class to use within the dialog
            param;              
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        } });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Errors i am getting are:

```
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

The method createDialog(String, String, Object) in the type Launcher is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, void)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define the DialogInterface.OnClickListener object for the Yes button in the onCreateDialog function, and then pass it to the createDialog function as a parameter, where you would use it to build the new dialog.

Comment: I have tried doing that, let me edit my answer so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i ended up doing this is the following:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_RIGHTTOLEFT:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Caution").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage("Do you need to apply Right to Left Patch? This is NOT Revertable!")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        RootCommands.doRightToLeft();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RTL Patch Applied. Please Reboot.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).create();
    case DIALOG_MOUNTNTFS:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Caution").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage("This will mount your external SDCard as NTFS and Break apps2sd. Continue?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        RootCommands.doMountNTFS();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "External SD Mounted as NTFS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).create();
    case DIALOG_MOUNTONBOOT:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Caution").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage("Mount external sd as NTFS at boot? This might cause issues.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        RootCommands.doMountOnBoot();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reboot to take effect.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).create();
    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

Question still applies; if anyone kinds a better solution to this, please share.